# Moodle Registration Form Edit

Tags: moodle

I am using moodle 2.8.1

My query is regarding Moodle registration form:

I want to add a confirm password field which would be required same as Email(again) field.

And remove the Email(again) field.

And also it is not showing the phone no. fields in registration form while they are unlocked.

Comment: I found the solution: I edited the file login\signup_form.php according my needs.

Comment: This is not upgrade safe I suppose

Comment: You are right @Alex, But at that time(6 years ago) I needed the quick solution. And no one was responding to the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add fields to the  registration form, you can do it using user profile fields in Site administration > Users > Accounts > User profile fields.

You have to set 'Display on signup page', which will show the field in the signup form, and 'Who is this field visible to' .

If you need more details refer: http://docs.moodle.org/26/en/User_profile_fields

Hope this helps.

Comment: But they will display in an other legend down the page, while confirm password should be just below the password field.

Comment: also it causes the password to be stored plain text in the database

Answer (score 1):

We made a [small open source module](https://github.com/iMi-digital/moodle-password-validation/) covering this use case.

It adds the field on the fly in the registration form, along with the necessary validation, using addRule and the compare rule.

Answer (score 0):

In order to add confirm password field, you can custom `login/signup_form.php` file by adding one more field right after password field with compare rule like:

```
$mform->addElement('password', 'confirmPassword', get_string('password_confirm'), 'maxlength="32" size="12"');
$mform->setType('password', core_user::get_property_type('password'));
$mform->addRule('confirmPassword', get_string('missingpassword'), 'required', null, 'client');
$mform->addRule(array('confirmPassword', 'password'), get_string('passwords_must_match'), 'compare', 'eq', 'client');
```