# Add a confirm password field moodle

Tags: php, html, forms, registration, moodle

How do I go about adding another field (password again) on moodle's default registration page?

I have tried to edit this file /login/signup_form.php.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Moodle Registration Form Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27897615/moodle-registration-form-edit)

Comment: Not really, I needed something a bit different.

Comment: we made a small module covering this https://github.com/iMi-digital/moodle-password-validation/